# How do you mulitply via addition?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to
compute x * y using only addition, printing the intermediate result for each loop iteration, and
printing the final number. This is my
[teacher's example of what the output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Mh4.png)

I could really use some help figuring it out,, I don't really understand how to yet.

Edit: I am a first time coder so I'm not very skilled, I do know the basics though (Also very new to this website) Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
x = int(input("Input positive x: "))
y = int(input("Input positive y: "))
z = 0
w = 0
if x < 0:
    exit("Please input a positive number for x")
if y < 0:
    exit("Please input a positive number for y")
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand, exactly? Are you able to write a loop at all? Are you able to add numbers together? What do you imagine to be the logical steps of the problem?

Comment: Have you written any programs at all before this? Could we see what level of understanding we're dealing with, here?

Comment: Edit the question. "Basic knowledge" does not help us understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try thinking of multiplication as adding a number with itself by x times. Hence, 3*4 = 3+3+3+3 = 12, which is adding 3 by itself 4 times

Replicating this with a for loop:

```
#inputs
x = 3
y = 4
#output
iteration = 1
result = 0

for num in range(4):
    result += x
    print(f'Sum after iteration {iteration}: {result}')
    iteration += 1 #iteration counter
```

The resulting output will be:

> Sum after iteration 1: 3 
> Sum after iteration 2: 6
>  Sum after iteration
> 3: 9
>  Sum after iteration 4: 12

Answer (score 2):

```
def multiplier(number, iterations):
    for i in range(1, iterations):
        number = number + 3

    print(number) # 12


multiplier(number=3, iterations=4)
```

My answer. Little shorter than the others.

Answer (score 0):

The code is simple and straightforward,Check which number is bigger and iterate according to that number.

```
x = 3
y = 4
out = 0
if x > y:
    for v in range(0,x):
        out += y
        print("after iteration",v+1, ":", out)
if y > x:
    for v in range(0,y):
        out += x
        print("after iteration",v+1, ":", out)
print(x,"*", y, "=", out)
```

Use print to print inside the loop to show each number after adding and the number of iteration occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. This assume both arguments are integers `0` or more:

```
def m(n1, n1a):
   n1b = 0
   while n1a > 0:
      n1b += n1
      n1a -= 1
   return n1b

n = m(9, 8)
print(n == 72)
```